# Elliptic Integral with exponential function.

Tags: elliptic-integrals, poissons-equation

$$I = \int_0^\pi{e^{-b\sqrt{a-cos(x)}}\over \sqrt{a-cos(x)}}dx$$

I have some understanding of elliptic integrals but I encountered this one while working with Screened Coulomb Potential and I have literally no idea how to proceed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A first try would be to substitute $t=\sqrt{a-\cos x}$, did you try it?!

Comment: Yeah, but I think it has made things more complicated... $$\int_\sqrt{a-1}^\sqrt{a+1}{e^{-bt} \over \sqrt{1-a^2+t^4-2at^2}}dt$$

Comment: Yeah, but i am desperately searching for a starting point, here may be one. Let us denote the above integral by $F(b)$, and we use $b$ as a parameter. For $F(0)$ we indeed see an elliptic integral, this is already a bad message. But then we may try to look at something like $(1-a^2)F(b) -2a \partial^2F(b) + \partial^4 F$, the square root from the denominator walks to the numerator, then we may try to apply partial integration by integrating the exponential, then in the main term the radical goes down again, some garbage polynomial terms appear, but we have a differential equation...

Comment: Sorry Dan, some urgent work came up and I couldn't reply. I actually saw your response 2 days ago. I am working on the idea you gave, so far no avail, but I promise to keep you notified. Thanks once again!